# ¿Cómo puedo clonar sin el val y eliminar del DOM la clase?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Creo que mi problema es sencillo. Sin embargo aún no logro dar con el. Necesito clonar una clase llamada .person_languages que contiene un input y un elemento a, sin embargo quiero que al clonar no se clone el value del input por que son values que cargaré desde la base de datos y no se deben de repetir.

Otro punto a tener en cuenta, ¿Cómo elimino del DOM la clase .person_languages cuando le de clic en .remove-language?

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add-field').click(function(){
    $('.person_languages:last').clone().insertBefore(".add-field");
  });  
});
```

```css
.add-field,
.remove-field {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.add-field{
  display: block;
  margin:10px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:inherit;
}

.remove-field{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  right:30px;
  background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/25-free-ui-icons/40/trash_bin-64.png);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-9">
                  <div class="person_languages">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" value="Spanish">
                    <a class="remove-language remove-field">x</a>
                  </div>
                  <a class="add-field">Add Language</a>
                </div>
    

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

La siguiente imagen contiene un campo input, el cual el value es extraído de la base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento clonarlo, también me clona el value y es algo que yo no quiero.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que quede vacio, de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y además, quiero que cuando le di clic al botecito de basura, elimine del DOM la clase .person_languages.

Comment: Podrïas ser un poco más específico con lo que quieres lograr? puedes agregar alguna imagen de cómo debería quedar??

Comment: @IsaacVega ¡Listo! Si sigues teniendo dudas, comentame, por favor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar clonar el `value` del `input` después de que se clono el `DOM` buscamos el `input` y le asignamos como `value = ""`

```
$('.add-field').click(function(){
  $('.person_languages:last').clone().insertBefore(".add-field").find('input').val("");
});
```

Si quieres eliminar cualquier `input` buscamos el elemento con el icono de basura

```
$('.remove-field').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Pero en esta función solo funcionara con un elemento que ya estuvo cargado con el `DOM` así que esta función no aplica una propagación a elementos dinámicos;
Entonces necesitamos modificar un poco la función:

```
$('.person_languages').parent().on('click', '.remove-field',function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

seleccionamos el elemento que contiene todos los elementos dinámicos, en este caso el `<div class="col-md-9">...</div>` es por eso que se hace de la siguiente manera `$('.person_languages').parent()` dentro de la funcion `on()` pongo el evento, seguido por el selector al que aplicaría el evento clic y por ultimo la función para eliminar el elemento.

[te anexo una referencia para que entiendas mejor este ultimo contexto](http://www.arumeinformatica.es/blog/jquery-asociar-eventos-a-elementos-html-creados-dinamicamente/)

Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add-field').click(function(){
    $('.person_languages:last').clone().insertBefore(".add-field").find('input').val("");
  }); 
  $('.person_languages').parent().on('click', '.remove-field',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.add-field,
.remove-field {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.add-field{
  display: block;
  margin:10px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:inherit;
}

.remove-field{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  right:30px;
  background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/25-free-ui-icons/40/trash_bin-64.png);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-9">
                  <div class="person_languages">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" value="Spanish">
                    <a class="remove-language remove-field">x</a>
                  </div>
                  <a class="add-field">Add Language</a>
                </div>
    

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```